# Python error: "global name 'counter1' is not defined"

Tags: python, variables, counter, global, defined

My code:

```css
class Persistence:
    num = 0
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    #num = input("Enter a non-negative number:: ")
    if num < 0:
        raise NameError("Negative")
    #test else:
        #print "ok!"
    num_list = []
    def digitize(self, num):
        num_list = []
        n = str(num)
        for digit in n:
            num_list.append(int(digit))
        return num_list
    def sum_digits(self, num):
        the_list = self.digitize(num)
        the_sum = 0
        for digit in the_list:
            the_sum = the_sum + digit
        return the_sum
    def times_digits(self, num):
        the_list = self.digitize(num)
        the_product = 0
        for digit in the_list:
            the_product = the_product * digit
        return the_product
    def additive(self, num):
        global counter1
        sum1 = self.sum_digits(num)
        list1 = []
        list1 = self.digitize(sum1)
        if list1.__len__() > 1:
            global counter1
            counter1 = counter1 + 1
            self.additive(sum1)
        return sum1, counter1
    def multiplicative(self, num):
        global counter2
        prod1 = self.times_digits(num)
        list1 = []
        list1 = self.digitize(prod1)
        if list1.__len__() > 1:
            global counter1
            counter2 = counter2 + 1
            self.multiplicative(prod1)
        return prod1, counter2

c = Persistence(5)
print c.additive(5)
print c.multiplicative(5)
```

Not sure why I'm getting this error? It seems to me that I have defined the global variable counter1. I'm also getting this error for counter2, and the only way I've been able to resolve the error is by inserting counter1 = 0 (or any other number) a single line above the return statement on the additive() method. Help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Please provide the full traceback in your question.

Comment: Instead of making them global, use `Persistence.counter1` to access it, or make it an instance attribute.

Comment: You made it a class attribute instead of a global variable. As per L3viathan's comment, use `Persistence.counter1`, or `self.counter1`. Generally, avoid global variables anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to move the counters out of class like:

```
  # global variables
    num = 0
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0

    class Persistence:
        ....
        ....
```

Leave the rest of your code unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

`counter1` and `counter2` are defined as class attributes currently, if you want to keep it that way, just access them as *`classname`*.*`attrname`*:

```
class Persistence:
    num = 0
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    #num = input("Enter a non-negative number:: ")
    if num < 0:
        raise NameError("Negative")
    #test else:
        #print "ok!"
    num_list = []
    def digitize(self, num):
        ...
    def sum_digits(self, num):
        ...
    def times_digits(self, num):
        ...
    def additive(self, num):
        sum1 = self.sum_digits(num)
        list1 = []
        list1 = self.digitize(sum1)
        if list1.__len__() > 1:
            Persistence.counter1 = Persistence.counter1 + 1
            self.additive(sum1)
        return sum1, Persistence.counter1
    def multiplicative(self, num):
        prod1 = self.times_digits(num)
        list1 = []
        list1 = self.digitize(prod1)
        if list1.__len__() > 1:
            Persistence.counter2 = Persistence.counter2 + 1
            self.multiplicative(prod1)
        return prod1, Persistence.counter2

c = Persistence(5)
print c.additive(5)
print c.multiplicative(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way of solving this issue will be to move the 3 class variables to **init** method. These variable will become associated with the object can be accessed using 'self'

```python
class Persistence(object):
    def __init__(self):     
        self.counter1 = 0
        self.counter2 = 0        

    def digitize(self, num):
        return [int(digit) for digit in str(num)]

    def sum_digits(self, num):
        return sum(self.digitize(num))

    def times_digits(self, num):
        the_list = self.digitize(num)
        the_product = 0
        for digit in the_list:
            the_product = the_product * digit
        return the_product

    def additive(self, num):
        sum1 = self.sum_digits(num)
        list1 = []
        list1 = self.digitize(sum1)
        if len(list1) > 1:
            self.counter1 += 1
            self.additive(sum1)
        return sum1, self.counter1

    def multiplicative(self, num):
        prod1 = self.times_digits(num)
        list1 = []
        list1 = self.digitize(prod1)
        if len(list1) > 1:
            self.counter2 += 1
            self.multiplicative(prod1)
        return prod1, self.counter2

c = Persistence()
print c.additive(5)
print c.multiplicative(5)
```

You don't num in the constructor if you are not actually using it.